# Getting control id within javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have created my own code to provide date masking and validation for TextBox control in asp.net. Below is the code. The code works perfectly.

function IsValidDate(ctrlID)
   {
        var validDate=true;

```
    var myT=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CandidateResume1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_Education1_"+ctrlID);
    var mm=myT.value.substring(0,2);
    var dd=myT.value.substring(5,3);
    var yy=myT.value.substring(6);

    if(mm!=0 && mm>12){
        myT.value=""; validDate=false;
    }
    else
    {
        if((yy % 4 == 0 && yy % 100 != 0) || yy % 400 == 0)
        {
            if(mm==2 && dd>29){
                myT.value=""; validDate=false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(mm==2 && dd>28){
                myT.value=""; validDate=false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(dd!=0 && dd>31){
                    myT.value=""; validDate=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if((mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11) && (dd!=0 && dd>30)){
                        myT.value="";  validDate=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(validDate==false)
    {
        myT.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000';
        myT.focus;
    }
    else
        myT.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';
}

function maskDate(ctrlID)
{
    var myT=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CandidateResume1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_Education1_"+ctrlID);
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? window.event.keyCode : 0;        
    if((KeyID>=48 && KeyID<=57) || KeyID==8)
    {
        if(KeyID==8)
            return;

        if(myT.value.length==2)
        {
            myT.value=myT.value+"/";
        }
        if(myT.value.length==5)
        {
            myT.value=myT.value+"/";            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        window.event.keyCode=0;
    }
```

### }

The problem -

I am attaching these functions to the textbox as -
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onFocusout","IsValidDate('TextBox1');");
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress","maskDate('TextBox1');");

If you look at the javascript code I have collected the control id in myT variable. I have also passed the id of textbox while attaching the js functions using Attributes.Add()

My problem is that i dont want to pass the id of the textbox as i am already attaching it. That is i want to write the code as

TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onFocusout","IsValidDate();");
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress","maskDate();");

My question is how can i get the id of textbox to which i have attached these functions witin JS code.

NOTE: I DONT WANT TO PASS CONTROL NAME OR CONTROLS CLIENTID WHILE ADDING ATTRIBUTES. PLEASE NOTE THAT I WANT TO REPLACE

TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onFocusout","IsValidDate('TextBox1');");
WITH
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onFocusout","IsValidDate();");
I WANT TO ATTACH THESE FUNCTIONS WITH MULTIPLE TEXTBOXES.

AS I AM USING .Attributes.Add(...) I WANT TO GET THE SAME CONTROLS CLIENTID WITHIN JS CODE.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Mohammad Irfan

Answer (score 1):

var txtControl = document.getElementById("<%= txtControl.ClientID %>");

Answer (score 0):

Control.ClientID

Comment: My friend, i am asking about the id of control within javascript code not in aspx code.

Comment: And ClientID gives you exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Either pass `TextBox1.ClientID` to the function, or change the function call to be `IsValidDate(this.id)`. But as you don't want to pass these in, you can place the TextBox1.ClientID in your javascript or use jquery to find it using $('[id*=TextBox1]').